# Unable to git add <file> using system2 from R script

Tags: r, system2

I am trying to add a file using git add. Note:  I am *very* new to git.

Using Ubuntu Linux

From a terminal prompt, this works.

`/usr/bin/git add static/fb/img/gic1-5_yield_curve_5bd11b935bd72745.png`

I can confirm that it works by doing `git status` and seeing the filename under, *Changes to be committed:*

I want to be able to do the same thing from an R script. This does not work:

`system2(command = "/usr/bin/git", args = c("add", "static/fb/img/gic1-5_yield_curve_5bd11b935bd72745.png"))`

Why is this?

Comment: Are you certain that R is working in the same directory that you tested in the terminal shell? `getwd()` will tell you that.

Comment: getwd() shows me I'm in an unhelpful directory. I didn't think that matters if I'm using these long, absolute path names. The command to system2 starts at root. The 1st arg is "add" and second argument has a full path name that begins at root. It's a little different that what I put in the question.

Comment: `"static/fb/img/gic1-5_yield_curve_5bd11b935bd72745.png"` is relative, not absolute. Unless your root directory is a git repo (unlikely and strongly discouraged), then `git` will fail with something like `fatal: not a git repository`. You can either `setwd(...)` somewhere within the git repo, or add `-C /path/to/gitrepo` to the command line.

Comment: I understand. I think I confused the issue my not posting the actual path names that look like: /home/me/website/static/fb/img/gic1-5_yield_curve_5bd11b935bd72745.png

Comment: Okay, I understand. But ... if R is not in the git repo directory or a sub-dir of the directory, then you must either `setwd(..)` before calling `git` or add `-C ...`. This is a limitation of `git`, not R.

Comment: R is definitely NOT  in the git repo directory or a sub-dir of the directory. So before I do the system2 call I need to set my working directory to where? R(usr/bin/R) , the head of the local repo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226334/discussion-between-ixodid-and-r2evans).

Comment: If your git repo is `/home/me/website/`, then one of: (1) `setwd("/home/me/website"); system2(asbefore)`; or (2) `system2("git",c("-C","/home/me/website","add",...))`.

Comment: setwd("/home/me/website"); system2(asbefore) This worked. Thank-you very much for your patient help r2evans.